# installing lxml via cmd

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pip

I am trying to install a lxml file but I am getting several errors. Most notable when I enter the command:

```
python lxml.py install
```

I get two error messages as shown in image

[image]

When I try addressing for that problem and manually type the command

```
python -m pip install lxml-3.6.0-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl
```

I am introduced to the error as shown in the image:

[image]

Would anyone have advice on how to work with this? I have this 1xm1-3.6. file manually installed but I feel that I am inexperienced on how to use that to be manually installed into the python directory. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the solution to my problem is as follows:

1- I installed mingw installation manager and downloaded the corresponding packages

2- Afterwards I ran ***python -m pip install lxml-3.6.0-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl*** which worked. Thanks to minGW.

3- I then ran ***python -m pip install pptx***

and that was the solution to my problem. I hope this helped anyone who would have the following problems.